# A possible characterization of weakly compact cardinals

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals, infinite-combinatorics

Aside from the well-known characterization of weakly compact cardinals in terms of the usual partition calculus, I've been wondering if there are other characterizations that are variants of the typical monochromatic partition relations we are considering. More precisely:

Do the following partition relations characterize weakly compact cardinals (all cardinals discussed in the following are inaccessible):

- $\begin{pmatrix} \kappa \\ \kappa \end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} \kappa \\ \kappa \end{pmatrix}^2_{\omega, <\omega}$, namely, for any  $f: \kappa\times \kappa\to \omega$, there exist $A,B\in [\kappa]^\kappa$ such that $|f''A\times B|<\aleph_0$. Notice that this property implies $\neg \square(\kappa)$ by a result of Todorcevic, so in particular $\kappa$ is weakly compact in $L$. I'm also interested in the case where $<\omega$ is replaced by $<3$.
- What about unpolarized partition relations in the square bracket family? $\kappa \to [\kappa]^2_{\omega}$, i.e. for any $f:[\kappa]^2\to \omega$, there exists $A\in [\kappa]^\kappa$ such that $f''A \neq \omega$. Or maybe we can even require $f''A$ to be finite.

Comment: Do you already know one direction? For example, you know that this property implies weak compactness? Or do you want to know about both directions?

Comment: Yeah I'm mainly concerned with whether they imply weak compactness since they are all consequences of wc

Comment: Do you assume $\kappa$ is regular or that $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$? This matters for some characterizations of weak compactness. For example, the weakly compact embedding property, by itself, does not imply weak compactness if $\kappa$ is not inaccessible. Also, the tree property requires inaccessibility to imply weak compactness.

Comment: Yes kappa is strongly inaccessible here

Comment: Your 2nd question is essentially Question 8.1.14 on page 238 of Todorcevic's book "Walks on Ordinals and their Characteristics".

Comment: I see. Actually I don't even know the answer $\omega$ is replaced by some finite number $>2$.